# Bad experience with the organization - should I send an email to that person

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, internship, unprofessional-behavior

I recently came across a job posted by some non-profit organization(or1) who provides grants to the interns and help students in collaborating with the industry.

I sent my resume to that org. and after few week, the industry partner(org2) called and schedule an interview with me.I appeared for the interview and got the job offer(not the offer letter).To make sure, I asked if I considered myself hired, the guy(org2) said answered positively.

The org1 enforces some rules for example, it should be a research project, one needs a supervisor and a approval is needed(by third party reviewer) which takes 1 month of time.

After hiring me, org2 said they were not aware about this thing as it is their first collaboration with org1.In the end, it came out that it is not even a research project that was previously advertised on org1 website.So, org2 declined my offer after 1 month by saying that they want to pursue it internally.

In the whole scenario, for me org1 is at fault because they never tell the proess to org2 and to me.And I was even hired and declined other offers just because org2 is a reputed company.

Question is Should I send an email saying that its my worst experience with the org1 guy and their business practices.

Is it acceptable? I know sending an email does nothing.

What do you think I should do? I am looking for new opportunities.

Comment: Why would you want to send it if you already know it does nothing?

Comment: does nothing in terms of the offer that I lost.But if I send the email, that's definitely give some food of thought to that person on how he should deal with all these things because it din't work out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't know whether the problem was org1's or org2's -- you just know that org2 blamed org1. It could just as easily be the case that org2 never bothered to read the rules, or knew them but hoped to cheat around them. Or *both* groups may have messed this up in equal measure.

If you want to send a note complaining about this to org1, just say "this happened, is there any way we can keep it from happening again". Don't blame either group, since you don't have the evidence to do so. At most, you can report that org2 blamed org1, and suggest that it might have been useful if the volunteers got a bit more information about what jobs will and won't be sponsored so they can help org1 catch errors earlier in the process.

Keep it constructive, not complaining or accusatory, and org1 might not only pay attention to your note but thank you for sending it.

If you just want to rant: Write the note in a text editor rather than in your e-mail program... and then delete the file. That'll get it out of your system without making matters worse. Then, after you've calmed down, consider what I've said above.

Final thought: If you're ever tempted to write a nasty note, do NOT hit send immediately. Write it, set it aside for at least 24 hours (preferably longer), then re-read what you've written and think about whether it's really supported and justified, and whether being nasty will accomplish your actual goals. That pause for reflection is TREMENDOUSLY useful in preserving your own reputation and in getting useful changes made.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words.This is happening with me for the second time.I will keep it constructive.